# Extracting numbers that include comma from a string, and convert it into numeric array

Tags: regex, arrays, r

I am trying to extract numbers from a sentence, and then put the numbers together as a numeric array. For example,

```
  string<-"  The Team:  $74,810 TOTAL RAISED SO FARJOIN THE TEAM Vik Muniz 
             Amount Raised: $70,560   71% Raised of $100,000 Goal CDI International,
             Inc.  Amount Raised: $2,070  Robert Goodwin Amount Raised: $1,500 
             30% Raised of $5,000 Goal Marcel Fukayama Amount Raised: 
             $210  Maitê Proença Amount Raised: $140  
             Thiago Nascimento Amount Raised: $120  
             Lydia Kroeger Amount Raised: $80  "
```

in order to proceed, I first removed the comma so that I can extract numbers easily:

```
    string.nocomma <- gsub(',', '', string)
```

and then I tried to put the numbers together as a numeric vector:

```
    fund.numbers <-unique(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]"," ",string.nocomma),""))
```

and here are the problems:

1. R is throwing an error after the last command. The error is as follow:

   ```
   Warning message:
   In unique(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", " ", website.fund.nocomma),  :
   NAs introduced by coercion
   ```
2. Even if I fix the above error and have the numeric vector, I am not sure how to convert numeric vector into an numeric array.

   Can someone help me?
   Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way :

```
## Extract all numbers and commas
numbers <- unlist(regmatches(string, gregexpr("[0-9,]+", string)))
## Delete commas
numbers <- gsub(",", "", numbers)
## Delete empty strings (when only one comma has been extracted)
numbers <- numbers[numbers != ""]
numbers

# [1] "74810"  "70560"  "71"     "100000" "2070"   "1500"   "30"    
# [8] "5000"   "210"    "140"    "120"    "80"
```

Answer (score 1):

After you applied gsub(), you have a string with numbers and spaces, so it's not possible to convert it to numeric directly. What you need it a numeric vector. I think it's better to use `gregexpr` to get it:

```
## get list of string with numbers only
> res = regmatches(string.nocomma, gregexpr("([0-9]+)", string.nocomma))
## convert it to numeric
> res = as.numeric(unlist(res))

 [1]  74810  70560     71 100000   2070   1500     30   5000    210    140    120
[12]     80
```